# Redirect 301 htaccess

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Дорогие друзья, помогите понять, как сделать 301 редирект при помощи htaccess для вот такой страницы:

```
http://site.ru/?yyy=hhh
```

Необходимо:
чтобы при посещении страницы `http://site.ru/?yyy=hhh` пользователя сразу же перебрасывало на `http://site.ru/yyy`.

Никак не могу написать правило для переноса. Походу, все утыкается в вопрос сразу после слеша.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^yyy=hhh$
RewriteRule .* /yyy? [R=301,L]
# ? - чтобы исключить добавление строки запроса к новому url

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yyy$
RewriteRule .* /?yyy=hhh&v [R=301,L]
# &v - чтобы избежать циклического редиректа
```